# Perl sFTP : how to check remote file doesnt exist

Tags: perl, sftp

I am 1 day old to Perl, was going through [API doc here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign), have few basic questions

```
  $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, autodie => 1);
  my $ls = $sftp->ls("/bar");
  # dies as: "Couldn't open remote dir '/bar': No such file"
```

**Question**

- with autodie will the connection be auto closed ?
- we see in above example how to use folder , similar syntax also works for file ?

Or something like this makes more sense ??

```
  my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, autodie => 1);
  $sftp->find("/sdfjkalshfl", # nonexistent directory
              on_error => sub { print "foo!\n";sftp->disconnect();exit; });
```

I was trying to run following code on my windows machine

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my $host = "demo.wftpserver.com";
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host ,ssh_cmd => 'plink',autodie => 1);
my $ls = $sftp->ls("/bar");
```

But i get error

> 'plink' is not recognized as an internal or external command ,

however when i run plink from windows command line it works fine !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with autodie will the connection be auto closed ?

**Yes.** When the program ends, everything is destroyed and connections are closed. That is also the case when the `$sftp` variable goes out of scope. Modules like this usually implement [a `DESTROY` sub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Destructors). Those are invoked when the object (which is just a reference in Perl) goes out of scope. There can be some cleanup in that sub. Another example that has that is DBI, and of course lexical filehandles (like `$fh` from a `open` call).

> we see in above example how to use folder , similar syntax also works for file ?

**No.** [The docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#sftp-ls-remote-opts) say `ls` is for a directory:

> Fetches a listing of the remote directory $remote. If $remote is not given, the current remote working directory is listed.

But you can just do `ls` for the directory that the file you want is in, and use the `wanted` option.

```
my $ls = $sftp->ls( '/home/foo', wanted => qr/^filename.txt$/ );
```

Though with the `autodie` that should die, so if you don't want it to actually die here, you should wrap it in a [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) call or an `eval`.

```
use Try::Tiny

# ...

my $ls = try { 
  return $sftp->ls( '/home/foo', wanted => qr/^filename.txt$/ );
} catch {
  return; # will return undef
};

say 'Found file "filename.txt" on remote server' if $ls;
```

---

As to `plink` being not found, probably the Windows `PATH` is different from what your Perl sees.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response (1 ) for plink i am using Padre Perl IDE , not sure if setting PATH is different for Windows & Padre ... can you please advice ( 2 ) can find be used for checking file name or only ls may be used

Comment: 2) the docs say find searches recursively. I guess that would work. Why don't you try it. 1) I have no experience with Padre and I do not have a Windows machine available to test. Try providing a full absolute path.

Comment: my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host ,ssh_cmd => 'C:/plink/plink-1.07-dos/plink',autodie => 1); or my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host ,ssh_cmd => 'C:\plink\plink-1.07-dos\plink',autodie => 1); ....
above line gives me  bad remote message received at test.pl